# How to load a UIViewController programmatically without using Storyboard in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have a ViewController called MyViewController and I want to load it programmatically without a stroyboard or xib.

As a follow up squestion, I would like to load a MyTableViewController inside a navigation controller. Again, I need to do it programmatically without using Storyboard or xib.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve my issue by removing the Storyboard and using the following code in AppDelegate

```
    import UIKit
    import CoreData

    @UIApplicationMain
    class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        var window: UIWindow?
        var navigationController: UINavigationController?

        func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
            // Override point for customization after application launch.
            self.window!.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
            self.window!.makeKeyAndVisible()

            let myViewController: MyViewViewController? = MyViewViewController()
            self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: myViewController!)
            self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController
            return true
        }
 ...
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote? I agree it's silly to do it this way, but this seems like the right answer for the question. If you want to down-vote, tell the OP why.

Comment: Why write a bunch of code when storyboards make this much easier? It's not appreciably more efficient, but introduces possible points of programming errors. The [View Controller Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/) no longer even contemplates programmatically built views, like it used to do. It used to have a long section on how to write `loadView` methods (not to be confused with `viewDidLoad`) for programmatically controlled views, but they apparently just assume that no one would be doing that any more.

Comment: Storyboards make it harder to merge when there are multiple developers working on the same project. You would have to manually edit the xml to resolve merge conflicts. Also, it is not scalable to use drag-and-drop to create each screen if you have more than a few screens in your app.

Comment: Manually creating your UI in code is silly for a multitude of reasons. IB has many thousands of hours of testing behind it. It creates UI elements that work. It makes localizing your UI trivial. It supports lots of features that make programming easier. It makes you much more productive. I would argue the exact opposite about being scalable. Creating lots of custom code in UI is not "scalable". It's slow, tedious, and error-prone to develop, and a nightmare to maintain.

Comment: That said, I wouldn't down-vote your answer because it's a reasonable answer to the question you asked.

Comment: I definitely appreciate the points you have made but I feel that if IB really wanted to solve developer's problems, it would generate a human-readable and git-diffable backing format (human-readable-xml or human-readable-json). That would give developers the option to work seamlessly in both IB and code without causing merging issues but as far as I can tell, IB still mixes Xcode-state with view-state in the storyboards xml resulting in unmergeable diffs in the backing xml of storyboards. For this reason, Google doesn't let iOS developers commit storyboards to version control.

Comment: The question and its answer is a useful example of another way to customize instantiation of an initial view controller, with or without a storyboard or nib. There are certainly valid reasons why someone might choose to create their interface entirely with code.

Comment: @Das - Hey, if it works for you, that's great. But, if you're worried about large development teams, I'd advise that NIB-based development should be considered before jumping right to programmatically implemented UI. NIBs mitigate the management issues of storyboards, while still enjoying the rapid development and easier code management enjoyed when using Interface Builder. Programmatically implemented views has it's place, but I wouldn't jump to that unless there was a compelling reason.

Comment: Thanks @Rob. I appreciate the inputs!!